# How to store a file in amazon s3 using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, rest

im new in s3 and i need some help please/

1.I get some file from rest api
its looks like

```
@PostMapping ("/aaa")
  public void aaa(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file)
```

how do i can put it to s3 without  saving in local like this

```
File f=new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
    file.transferTo(f);
    s3client.putObject("netapi", file.getOriginalFilename(),f);
```

i need to put file like it is - for example i put img.png to rest api and i need to get link from s3 to same file that be able to download and open without any converting on client pc

2.second question
is there any way to do not use MultipartFile in rest api - may be there is a way to covert inputStream that i can get from HttpServletRequest.getInputStream() to a file with same   file name and  file extension

i use sdk for java 1.X

```
implementation(group = "com.amazonaws",name="aws-java-sdk-s3",version = "1.11.1008")
```

Comment: I recommend moving to AWS SDK for Java V2. You can find many Amazon S3 examples here - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/s3

Comment: Please refer the implementation in https://github.com/Senthuran100/GPRCFileUpload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about working with a Spring Controller, you can get the byte array that represents the file like this:

```
//Upload an image to send to a S3 bucket
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            // Now i can add this to an S3 Bucket
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            String name =  file.getOriginalFilename() ;

           // Put the file into the bucket
            s3Client.putObject(bytes, "mybucket", name);
       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("photo"));
    }
```

YOu can use that byte array and file name to put the file into an Amazon S3 bucket without saving it as a local file.

To put this into an AMazon S3 bucket, you can use this code:

```
     // Places the file into a S3 bucket
     public String putObject(byte[] data, String bucketName, String objectKey) {
    
            s3 = getClient();
    
            try {
                //Put a file into the bucket
                PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                                .bucket(bucketName)
                                .key(objectKey)
                                .build(),
                        RequestBody.fromBytes(data));
    
                return response.eTag();
    
            } catch (S3Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
            return "";
        }

 private S3Client getClient() {
        // Create the S3Client object
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
                .region(region)
                .build();

        return s3;
    }
```

This code shows you how to handle a file that is posted to a Spring BOOT controller, how to get the file name and byte array, and how to put the file into an Amazon S3 bucket using V2 S3 code.

Comment: Its awesomne solution,very big thanks smac2020

Comment: Thank you - see the full AWS Multi Service tutorial here. It will walk you through the entire process - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app